# Javascript Regex test single quote, double quotes, forward and backslashes

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regex expression that will test if a given string has the following:

- single quote
- double quotes
- forward slash
- back slash

The string will be eventually coming from a JSON object.

here's what I have put together for testing purposes:

```
const validationRegex = new RegExp('[\'\"\\\/]+', 'g');
const name = `
myname\
`

let result = validationRegex.test(name)
console.log(result)
```

The result is "true" for the single quote, double quotes and ***forward slash*** which is the expected behavior. However for ***back slashes*** result is "false"

e.g.

```
const validationRegex = new RegExp('[\'\"\\\/]+', 'g');
const name = `
myname\
`

let result = validationRegex.test(name)
console.log(result) // false
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The `\\\/` part matches a single `/`. Use 4 backslashes in a constructor notation. Or declare with a regex literal - `validationRegex = /['"\\\/]/g`

Comment: @Wiktor that didn't work

Comment: You want to get `false` if a string contains one of these symbols inside `[...]`, right? So, you may use `/['"\\\/]/.test("name\\")` will return *false* because `"name\\"` string literal defines a literal string ``name\``